# Delete a dynamodb table from local container using AWS Workbench

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm trying to use DynamoDB locally and am using the container https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local combined with AWS Workbench (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html).

I have successfully created a table on my local container but now I wish to delete it. I'm assuming AWS Workbench has this functionality(?) and I'm just being dumb... can anybody point me at the button I need to press?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody else is looking, at time of writing aws workbench does not support the functionality to delete a table. Got my answer straight from the DynamoDb team.

Comment: You now can use PartiQL with NoSQL Workbench to query, insert, update, and delete table data in Amazon DynamoDB

Posted On: Dec 21, 2020

However, you cannot still delete the table from dynamodb.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72101529/1497760

Comment: Unsupported operation: DropTable , I tried running PartiQL operations in nosql workbench

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while trying to update data from NoSql Workbenck into my local DDB table.

My issue was now knowing how to re-commit/update the data after my first commit to [my local docker ddb server](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) as I was getting this error

```
Error
Could not commit to DynamoDB as table creation failed: ResourceInUseException: Cannot create preexisting table
```

What worked for me was to:

1. stop my local instance (`ctrl + c`)
2. restart my local ddb server (`docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local`)
3. and `commiting` my changes to my local DDB [again from NoSql Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.Visualizer.Commit.html)

Just in case anyone else is trying to solve the same problem and if you haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

[You now can use PartiQL with NoSQL Workbench to query, insert, update, and delete table data in Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/you-now-can-use-partiql-with-nosql-workbench-to-query-insert-update-and-delete-table-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/)

Posted On: Dec 21, 2020

However, you cannot still delete the table from dynamodb.